# How to implement Typescript async await pattern: Where is the Promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, typescript1.7

I'm learning angular and Typescript.

I have a CustomerService an in this service I Have a method which I wish to return an array of customers from a RESTfull service.

Initially I created my GetCustomers function thus:

```
public GetCustomers(): Dtos.ICustomer[] {

        var _customers: Dtos.ICustomer[];
        this._httpService.get('http://localhost/myTestApi/api/customers/')
            .success(function (data) {

                _customers = data as Dtos.ICustomer[];
            }).error(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        return _customers;
    }
```

This function eventually gets the customers but obviously it will return _customers before the httpservice actually gets the data.

At this point I thought I could make use of Typscript async/await   and this is when I end in a mess.

I wanted to write my function like this:

```
public async GetCustomers(): Dtos.ICustomer[] {

        var _customers: Dtos.ICustomer[];
        await this._httpService.get('http://localhost/myTestApi/api/customers/')
            .success(function (data) {

                _customers = data as Dtos.ICustomer[];
            }).error(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        return _customers;
    }
```

I immediately get this error: Error TS1055 Type 'Dtos.ICustomer[]' is not a valid async function return type.

I found this [Async/Await , simple example (typescript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32401741/async-await-simple-example-typescript)

however it uses an Promise object: return new Promise

If I attempt to re-write my GetCustomers method signature thus:

```
public async GetCustomers(): Promise<Dtos.ICustomer[]> {}
```

I get and error:

Cannot find name 'Promise'

Do I need to import something to get a Promise?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Async/Await , simple example (typescript)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32401741/async-await-simple-example-typescript)

Comment: Yes I saw that but on my end  Promise does not exist?  Typescript appears to know nothing about Promise.
if I change my method signature to public async GetCustomers(): Promise<Dtos.ICustomer[]>{...}
I get an error stating "Cannot find name 'Promise')

Comment: Well this certainly does make your question different from the linked one, please edit it to include this information.

Comment: Yes I realised this an have edited it appropriately I think.

Comment: Promise is declared in lib.es6.d.ts. Have you set `compilerOptions.target` to 'es6' in tsconfig.json?

Answer (score 2):

I would reccomend looking at the Angular $q Promise Object:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

It handles what you need for the promise.

```
public getCustomers(): ng.IPromise<Dtos.ICustomer[]> {
        var lDefer: ng.IDeferred<Dtos.ICustomer[]> =
            this.$q.defer<Dtos.ICustomer[]>();

        this._httpService.get('http://localhost/myTestApi/api/customers/')
            .then(( inResult: any ) => {
                let lResultList: Dtos.ICustomer[] = inResult.data;
                lDefer.resolve( lResultList );
            },
            ( inError: any ) => {
                lDefer.reject( inError );
            });

        return lDefer.promise;
    }
```

Make sure to inject the $q object in your controller:

```
import IPromise = angular.IPromise;
import IDeferred = angular.IDeferred;

static $inject = ['$q', ...];

constructor( protected $q:angular.IQService, ... ) {
    super( $q );
}
```

P.S. - There is a typing file available from Definitely Typed: http://definitelytyped.org/

You can install 'q' Typescript definition via **tsd** (Now Deprecated) or [**typings**](https://github.com/typings/typings)

Answer (score 0):

in your `tsconfig.json` file, under `compilerOptions`:

you need to add:

`"lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost",`**`"es2015.promise"`**`, "es2015"]`

I use es2015 target, but the lib exists for other targets too. 
in vscode, you'll have intellisense.