# Typescript async function wrapping promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, ionic-framework, async-await

I'm curerntly playing with `Typescript` and `ionic` and also new to `async-await` on javascript. I'm trying to get a good undestanding of promises but I can't figure out how to wrap methods which call multiple promises to return a promise. I'll try to elaborate better:

Basically, I have an object which can create a `SQLite` database, and when the `create()` method is invoked, it would return a `Promise` with the actual database object once it has been created.

**Then**, when the promise resolves and the DB object is returned, I need to use it to execute some statements in a transaction to create all the tables, and a new promise is returned when I invoke the execution of all the statements in the transaction.

**Then** when the transaction is finished and everything went good, I need to assign the database object to a class property and set a flag indicating database is created and ready to go.

So I thought it would be a good idea to wrap this database initialization stuff in a method called `createDatabase()` or something like that, which returns a `Promise<SQLiteObject>`, where `SQLiteObject` represents the database. This method would be called on initialization and should return the `SQLiteObject` representing the database once everything went OK, or throw an error which I would log in the `.catch()` method of the `Promise`.

I have a basic understanding of promises and how to use `then()` and `catch()` methods but I'm a bit confused when I have to create the database, then do something else when the promise resolves, and when everything is done, return a `Promise` containing the DB object, which is an instance of the class `SQLiteObject`.

---

**CODE**
Below is my current `Typescript` code. It's not valid typescript as I don't know how to return the `Promise<SQLiteObject>` from the `async` function.

```
async createDatabase(): Promise<SQLiteObject> {

        this.sqlite.create({
            name: this.dbName,
            location: this.dbLocation
        }).then( (db: SQLiteObject) => {
            // Insert all tables.
            let createTableParam: string = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS param (name PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, value TEXT)`;
            let createTableNews: string = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS news (id PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,title TEXT,
                content TEXT, image TEXT, date DATE)`;

            db.transaction(tx => {
                    tx.executeSql(createTableParam);
                    tx.executeSql(createTableNews);
                    // Add here more tables to create if needed
                }
            )
                .then( () => {
                    console.log('Tables were created');
                    this.isActive = true;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(`Error creating tables - ${error}`);
                });
        }).catch(
            error => console.log(`Error at SQLite initialization - ${error}`)
        );
    }
```

---

**RESEARCH SO FAR**

- I have read [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) which seems related but I am
  confused on how to implement on my code
- Checked [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) on MDN
- [This question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32401741/async-await-simple-example-typescript) also seems related but still don't really understand how to do it.
- [Typescript promises](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/promise.html) at "Typescript Deep Dive"
- [Async/Await](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/async-await.html) at "Typescript Deep Dive"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `async`, so that means you can use `await` inside the function any time you have a `Promise` and write the code almost as though it were synchronous.

```
async createDatabase(): Promise<SQLiteObject> {
    let db: SQLiteObject;
    try {
      db = await this.sqlite.create({
        name: this.dbName,
        location: this.dbLocation
      });
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(`Error at SQLite initialization - ${error}`);
        return;
    );
    // Insert all tables.
    let createTableParam: string = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS param (name PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, value TEXT)`;
    let createTableNews: string = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS news (id PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,title TEXT,
        content TEXT, image TEXT, date DATE)`;

     try {
       await db.transaction(tx => {
                tx.executeSql(createTableParam);
                tx.executeSql(createTableNews);
                // Add here more tables to create if needed
            }
          );

       console.log('Tables were created');
       this.isActive = true;
       return db;
     catch(error) {
         console.log(`Error creating tables - ${error}`);
     });
}
```

Without the `await` you need to be sure to return that initial promise.

```
return this.sqlite.create({...
```

and then again further down you can return the `db` object:

```
       this.isActive = true;
       return db;
```

Also you should avoid nesting the `.then()` handlers: when you get another promise just return it from the first handler and chain another `.then` on the end:

```
createDatabase(): Promise<SQLiteObject> {
    let database: SQLiteObject = null;
    return this.sqlite.create({
        name: this.dbName,
        location: this.dbLocation
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(`Error at SQLite initialization - ${error}`))
    .then( (db: SQLiteObject) => {
        // Insert all tables.
        let createTableParam: string = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS param (name PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, value TEXT)`;
        let createTableNews: string = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS news (id PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,title TEXT,
            content TEXT, image TEXT, date DATE)`;
        database = db;
        return db.transaction(tx => {
                tx.executeSql(createTableParam);
                tx.executeSql(createTableNews);
                // Add here more tables to create if needed
            }
        );
    })
    .then( () => {
        console.log('Tables were created');
        this.isActive = true;
        return database;
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(`Error creating tables - ${error}`));
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Ducan, is it a bad idea to use async yet? I read that on Typescript 2.1 it's supported and it will transpile to ES5 so I guess that there isn't any problem... Speaking about async, would it be a mess if I didn't use an async function and had to rely on managing `Promises` directly?

Comment: I presume you meant `let db; try {` not `try { const db` as the second will be an error when you use db later.

Comment: Good catch, I was refactoring on the fly there and added the `try{}` after I had already done the code inside it.

Comment: @JorgeGRC I added how the code might look without async. The transpilation to ES5 works for async but the code it produces can be quite verbose, so it's really just a choice to make whether you want verbose and possibly slower code executing in return for cleaner code at compile time.

Comment: Oh I see now, it's much clearer not going into the kind of "promise hell", thanks for this detail and guidelines, appreciate it so much

Answer (score 2):

It appears you're not resolving the promise.

A promise must be resolved or rejected so a async function is capable of responding with a value.

From TypeScript Deep Dive:

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(123);
});
promise.then((res) => {
    console.log('I get called:', res === 123); // I get called: true
});
promise.catch((err) => {
    // This is never called
});
```

So in my opinion you should create a promise, and when the DB is created and everything resolve it, if there's a problem with the DB creation, reject it.

Remember you can chain promises, so you could chain them as you create your database.

From TypeScript Deep Dive:

> The chain-ability of promises is the heart of the benefit that promises provide. Once you have a promise, from that point on, you use the then function to create a chain of promises.

Check this [URL](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/promise.html) for more info about promises.

Comment: Thanks for your time Henry, this answer is indeed also helpful but I'm accepting Duncan's one as it dives deep into detail. I do understand now what you wanted to point out creating a new promise and resolving when the database was created. Thanks

Comment: Just wanted to help :). I'm glad is a bit more clear to you now. Have a good day!